# Compare DateTimes in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to do this but it is not working, it returns empty results:

```
if (inputDate != null)
{
     dataContext.myTable
                .Where(r => r.myDate.HasValue && 
                            r.myDate.Value.Day == inputDate.Value.Day)
}
```

I want to compare two nullable `DateTime` values, I want to retrieve only `DateTime` values from database that belong to a certain `Date`. And to simplify this problem, I am trying first to compare only their `Day` value.

Please do not mark as duplicate, I am working with *EF5*, so I don't have `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()` function.

Comment: You could just use `r.myDate.Date == inputValue.Date`. Using `Day` means that you'll get matches regardless of the month.

Comment: Not working it gives an exception : *The specified membre 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities*. In fact EntityFramework does not reconize how to translate this code to sql

Comment: Try to remove `r.myDate.HasValue`  and than use `r.myDate.Date == inputValue.Date`

Comment: @S.Petrosov that would only work if the myDate column is a `DATE` column. If it is a `DATETIME` it would not.

Comment: I tried to remove HasValue and still not working. For .Date it gives an exception *The specified membre 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.*. And for .Day it gives empty result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, Entity Framework will throw an error. The best option you have is to use a query with a condition between the first second of the day and the last second of the day.

```
if(inputDate != null)
{
    /* Assuming inputDate.Value only contains the Date part.
       i.e. : 2017-05-23 instead of 2017-05-23 10:00:32 */
    DateTime inputDateFirstSecond = inputDate.Value;
    DateTime inputDateLastSecond = inputDateFirstSecond
        .AddHours(23)
        .AddMinutes(59)
        .AddSeconds(59);

    dataContext.myTable.Where(r => r.myDate.HasValue &&
        (r.myDate.Value >= inputDateFirstSecond && r.myDate.Value <= inputDateLastSecond)
    )
}
```

There are some Entity Framework Extensions for SQL Server that let you work with the datetime parts, but they would not work if you change your database engine in the future.

Comment: Thanks , you saved me a lot of times